# dotnet ef force me to have connectionString in appsettings.Development.json

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, appsettings

I always had connectionString in following files: `appsettings.json` and `appsettings.Development.json`. But then I realized. It's enough to have it one place - `appsettings.json`. Because it's replaced in CI builds anyway. So I removed it from there and application is still working fine.

But then I was trying to update database with command `dotnet ef database update --Context AppIdentityDbContext` and it turned out that i cannot because dotnet cannot find connection string

```
System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
 ---> System.InvalidOperationException: Could not find a connection string named 'Identity'.
```

So now I'm forced again to revert that connection string in `appsettings.Development.json`.

Is there anyway to get rid of it that connectionString from that file. I don't see any reason to keep in two places, just because of that minor reason.

Comment: From EF-Core 5, you can specify the connection string with the argument `--connection`, like `dotnet ef database update --Context AppIdentityDbContext --connection <ConnectionString>`

Comment: Give this a try:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52665058/dotnet-ef-does-not-respect-configuration

Comment: @vernou this isn't solution for me. Copying connectionString every time.

Comment: @SebastianBörgers I've seen this. But then it requires to have additional appsettings that will be picked based on `$env:ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT`. It's not solving my problem. Does it mean that there is no other way?